# C++ Encrypting and decrypting Lua files

Tags: c++, lua, encryption

I have a program (a small game) written in C++ that gets its configuration from Lua files (they are basically modules for the program). For instance, the program gets its name, version and what it is and isnt allowed to do and what the player can do from the Lua files. The problem is when I start distributing this small game to a few people they can configure the Lua files which I dont want to happen so I have thought of encrypting them and then decrypting them when the program starts but I just cannot grasp the concept of how to actually do it and in what way. All in all, is this a rather simple task as I imagine it to be?

How I see it is like this: Encrypt the lua files with some program in a certain encryption method. The write C++ code into the program that first decrypts the Lua files and then starts reading them. Is this concept correct? The encryption itself could be as weak as possible, as long as it works.

Comment: As an aside, why not just let people change the files?  People generally see being able to mod a game as a big bonus.   If you're worried about cheating, you could store a hash of each file so that you can detect if they've been modified, and display a warning (or, for example, disallow multiplayer sessions between people if their hashes are different from each other)

Comment: That is true, alot of people love being able to mod the game. The reason, like you thought it was, for me encrypting the Lua files is to  battle cheaters. If I was even able to encrypt or somehow block the modification of certain Lua files that can be modified to use cheats, then I would be happy. The rest of the Lua files could be left for the users to modify as they want. Implementing that hash feature would probably be too hard of a thing for me I believe or atleast I cant grasp the concept of it either yet so it seems very hard.

Answer (score 5):

By using luac I was finally able to make it all work.

I used this phrase to compile it with `luac` (in there, `tester.lua` is name of output file and `test.lua` is the file that is compiled):

```
luac -o tester.lua test.lua
```

It all works automatically, whether its compiled or not. Now the problem is, anyone could place the compiled lua file with a noncompiled version and it would still work because dofile reads both, normal and compiled lua. What would you fellas suggest as the solution so that dofile would only read compiled lua files and not uncompiled ones?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask a new question as a Question, rather than using an Answer to comment or ask a question. That said, it *is* allowed (and even encouraged) to Answer your own Question, so the notes about `luac` making it work for you are ok. I'll fix your formatting, however.

Comment: `luaL_loadfilex` and friends allow you to restrict loading to precompiled files.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's basically it.

Assuming at the moment you have something like

```
runLuaFromFile("config.lua");
```

you'd want to do

- load text file "config.lua" into memory (e.g. as a string)
- decrypt your string
- `runLuaFromMemory(myString);`

obviously the `runLuaFromFile` and `runLuaFromMemory` aren't real functions, they're just placeholders for whatever Lua system you're using

Answer (score 3):

Distributing precompiled Lua files instead of source will probably suffice for your purposes. See `luac`.

Comment: I have tried compiling info.lua with luac.

I used the following:  luac -o info.lua info.lua

But even then lua_dofile cannot read the file for some reason when the game loads.

Comment: Note that `luac -o info.lua info.lua` clobbers `info.lua`, though it works fine.